# Software updates on low permission users

Tags: installation, permissions, filesystems, software-update

**What I am looking for:**

Allowing my software to automatically update without administrator account and keeping it to the standard methods.

**The software setup**

The software is installed at:

- Program Files\MySoftwareName
- Program Files (x86)\MySoftwareName

**Solutions?**

I could make a group policy to create a restricted user on the clients machine which has write access to "MySoftwareName" and when user execute the auto-patcher. The auto-patcher will impersonate the restricted user account which has write access to the program files.
Though it just feels like I am doing a work around.

There isn't really any alternative locations that I could use for installing software that I am aware of.

From my understanding:

- `%AppData%` - Is settings against your profile which is suppose to be used for storing settings rather than installation of software.
- `%AllUsersProfile%` - Is computer settings which is computer specific.

So, I shouldn't be using any of these to install software too since they are based for settings/configuration and not software.

So, what do you guys think is best practise to allow end-user to update software without requiring administrator account?

- Alternative location to program files?
- Create a local restrictive account which has permissions to my folder within Program Files?
- Other?

Comment: Modify the permissions of the User group to allow the installation of updates and/or modify group policy to whitelist which programs can be installed.

Comment: Package it with an MSI installer and use Group Policy to distribute it and it's updates.

Comment: Thank you for your comment people. @techie007 I originally thought of this idea but from my understanding updates only effect during login of user, right? Thanks.

Comment: Or during start-up of the computer (so it installs with the System account). That way the users aren't installing the software, you are. :)

Comment: Only issue been is users barely ever log out they only shut them down on Friday. Doh. I think I'll stick with my original method and write myself an autopatcher with the restricted user account to stop the user been able to modify my files and doesn't allow the user to modify the files. I have voted your comment up though. Thanks for the help. I think it's me been too OCD. :)